# Implicit-Explicit Predictor-Corrector method for non-linear parabolic PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am working through a paper on implicit-explicit predictor-corrector scheme for non-linear parabolic PDE and having trouble understanding some concepts. I have this PDE:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}$ = $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ + $f(t,x,u)$

After spatial discretization by central difference operator, I have this:

$\frac{du}{dt}$ = $Au$ + $g(t,u)$

with $A$ a tridiagonal matrix and $g(t,u)$ a non-linear function. The author goes for a predictor-corrector scheme with an IMEX predictor and an implicit corrector:

predictor: $(a_{s}I - b_{s}kA)\tilde u_{n+s} = \sum_{j=0}^{s-1}(-a_{j}u_{n+j}+kb_{j}Au_{n+j}+kc_{j}g(t_{n+j},u_{n+j}))$

corrector: $(a_{s}I - b_{s}kA)u_{n+s} = \sum_{j=0}^{s-1}(-a_{j}u_{n+j}+kb_{j}Au_{n+j}+kb_{j}g(t_{n+j},u_{n+j}))+kb_{s}g(t_{n+s},\tilde u_{n+s})$

I've done the Taylor series expansion for the predictor and got the following order conditions:

$\sum_{j=0}^{s}a_{j}=0$

$\sum_{j=1}^{s}ja_{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{s}b_{j}=\sum_{j=0}^{s-1}c_{j}$

$\sum_{j=1}^{s}\frac{j^2}{2}a_{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{s}jb_{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{s-1}jc_{j}$

.

.

.

$\sum_{j=1}^{s}\frac{j^p}{p!}a_{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{s}\frac{j^{p-1}}{(p-1)!}b_{j}=\sum_{j=1}^{s-1}\frac{j^{p-1}}{(p-1)!}c_{j}$

Now, for example, if I take $s=1$, I get three order conditions for 5 unknowns, $a_{0},a_{1},b_{0},b_{1}$ and $c_{0}$. I would expect to use two parameters to formulate a solution for the system of linear equations but the author of the paper uses only one parameter $\gamma$, as follows:

$a_{0}=-1$, $a_{1}=1$, $b_{0}=1-\gamma$, $b_{1}=\gamma$, $c_{0}=1$

The above satisfies the system but how does he come up with this solution set? In fact he's right because there's actually a theorem that states that an s-step IMEX scheme should have s parameters. So am I missing some other order conditions or anything?

Thanks for any help on this issue.